# Why is this string not declared in the scope?

Tags: c++

I'm experimenting with classes and I'm wondering why I'm getting an error saying "calvin" is not defined in the scope. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class people
    {
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
    };

int main()
{
    people peeps[10];

    peeps[1].name = calvin;
    peeps[1].age = 21;

    cout << peeps[1].name << peeps[1].age;
}
```

Comment: `peeps[1].name = calvin;` --> `peeps[1].name = "calvin";`

Comment: Don't use arrays, use std::vector.

Comment: @UKMonkey no, but a beginner should simply stay with std::vector. std::array and array are advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Without quotes, `calvin` is a variable (which is undefined). You should make it a literal (i.e. `"calvin"`).

Answer (score 1):

firstly i would suggest if you had made and age private class members and also create get name/age and set name/age member functions to protect your data and finally

```
peeps[1].name = calvin; 
//calvin is an undefined variable
```

you should have used string literals for example

```
peeps[1].name = "calvin";
```